# Output current/voltage for PIC12F675

Tags: voltage, current, pic, basic

I want to get some clarification about output current and output voltage from a PIC12F675. As I read in datasheet, max. current for an output pin is 25 mA.

[image: Page 85 from DataSheet - mention max 25mA]

Is it always 25 mA, or will it depend in some settings? (Vdd = 5 V)?

And also, if Vdd is 5 V, the outout voltage will be Vdd - 0.7 V = 5 V - 0.7 V = 4.3 V. Or did I miss something?

[image]

Another question is: what does Ioh mean? I saw the sign "-" means current is sourced by a pin.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the datasheet, you'll see the "maximum output currents" are in the "Absolute Maximum Ratings" section, and there is a note beneath the table that explain if you exceed these values the part may well suffer permanent damage.

Values in this section aren't therefore what you should be planning to use in normal operation, rather they are what you should avoid exceeding under *all* operational states.

For current limits, this normally relates to thermal damage due to internal resistances.  Operating voltage does not normally significantly change this limit.

In terms of the Voh rating, each output will have drive structures for high and low, and these will have voltage/current relationships that vary according to supply voltage. The datasheets will commonly have graphs showing these relationship at various supply voltages.  There will also generally be tables giving minimum, typical and maximum under certain conditions.  These ranges allow you to produce designs with the required tolerance for part-to-part variations.

Ioh is the pin current (I) in output mode (o) at in the high (h) state.  The equivalent for low output current would be Iol.

The entry you quote says that the high output voltage (Voh) will be a minimum of Vdd-0.7V when the output (Ioh) is supplying 3mA and the supply (Vdd) is 4.5V.

The negative sign is simply convention, with currents being quoted in terms of current flowing *into* the pin (hence Iol are generally positive, and Ioh negative).

Answer (score 1):

25mA is for absolute maximum rating.

The table you're showing is from "DC Characteristics", which means a normal operating condition. It means when the load is drawing 3.0mA, the pin voltage will be VDD-0.7V. Thus, the voltage drop of P-channel MOSFET of output buffer will be 0.7V, between the VDD line and output pin.

Comment: If I will give Vdd=5V, I will get 4.3V on output pin and what current? Sorry, I`m new in this things, and can`t get the point with current.

Comment: @SkePsis No you read it wrong. It reads right there; you are guaranteed to get at least 3mA before voltage drops by  0.7V drop between VDD and VOUT. The ratings are for typical logic level operation when communicating with other chips, but it does not apply if you are trying to pull lots of current (not available) or don't care about logic level compatibility.

Comment: @SkePsis Output current varies what resistance load you'll connect between out pin and the ground. That condition in the datasheet means, they connected 1.433kohm resistor between output pin and the ground. If your load is smaller, you'll get bigger output current and the voltage will get a little lower than 4.3V, for example.

Comment: I want to use 2N7000 for PWM, but I don`t know PIN OUPUT ( Current + Voltage) to calculate the series resistor. I understand if Vdd is 5V will be 4.3V on pin output, but what about current?

Comment: A few(tens) uA will be there. 2N7000 is N-channel MOSFET. Its maximum Igss is rated as 100uA at 18V Vgs. You don't need to add any series resistor. For high speed switching, there might need to add some resistor and capacitors around Gate.
This means, if you directly connect the Gate to 5V or 4.3V or whatever, its current will be less than 100uA. MOSFTETs have Mohm range resistance for the resistance between G-S.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explanation. Could you also explain me what is the minim voltage applyedyou in base to let's say "activate" - "connect drain to source" ?